# Unable to install right version of mysql(8.0.13) on windows

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, python-3.x

I am a Windows user and very new with django and database.
My current group project requires to use django and mysql.
My teammate(macOS user) has already built a django web and I was trying to run the web by running it on virtualenv. I tried to download every required packages by 
typing `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Although, it downloaded most of the packages, but it did not allow me to install mysql==8.0.13. I tried other methods
such as `pip install mysql==8.0.13` or even trying it on ubuntu bash.

However, I always get this message....

`(virtualenv) C:\Users\ed>pip install mysql==8.0.13`

> Collecting mysql==8.0.13
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql==8.0.13 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2)
>   No matching distribution found for mysql==8.0.13**

So even after many tries, I could not find a solution so when I just type 
'py manage.py runserver' or 'python manage.py runserver', the results show like this....

`(virtualenv) C:\kim....\projectsite>py manage.py runserver`

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03585618>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: ??? ??? ?? ? ????.\r\n")
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edwardkim\Envs\shkim\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: ??? ??? ?? ? ????.\r\n")
```

I am stuck on this problem for such a long time and still not even able to run 
manage.py. Please help me with this problem and suggest me with any good solutions. Thank you for reading.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/, the current Generally Available (GA) release is v8.0.14, is there a reason you can't that? Also, [8.0.13 is available in the archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/), can you install it manually using the MSI?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the MySQL database with the Python library you need to use to interface with it.

`pip` only installs Python libraries. To install MySQL itself, you'll need to download it from their site: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ (or use a package manager, eg Chocolatey.

The Python library you need to install via `pip` is [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/).